# Error "An item with the same key has already been added" in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

i have added drop with some static value but its showing error

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MRStype, new SelectList(new List
{
new { Value = "0", Text = "--Select--"  },`enter code here`
new {Value = "1", Text = "Internal Issue"  },
new { Value = "2" , Text = "External Issue"  }
},
"value",
"text"
), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlSourceType" })

Answer (score 0):

Change your Code to this one (use List instead of List)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GlobalStudentId, new SelectList(new List<object> { new { Value = "0", Text = "--Select--" }, new { Value = "1", Text = "Internal Issue" }, new { Value = "2", Text = "External Issue" } }, "value", "text"), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlSourceType" })
```